# How does google's position.coordinates.speed translate into mph?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I've been messing around with Google Maps API. It returns a `position` object, with relevant bit being the following:

```
{
 "speed": 1.41837963
}
```

I have a number of readings from driving around the block ranging from -1, 0 (understandable since I was just sitting there) to about 19~. It seems about right considering how I was driving but how does this translate into approximate mph?

Comment: Which API endpoint are you hitting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your not using Google Maps to obtain the user's position, but instead using the [W3C Geolocation standard](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). [Speed](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#speed) is given in meters/second, so to convert to MPH just multiply the returned value by 2.23694.

If your code contains something like `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` or `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()`, then speed is given in m/s. If, however, the above methods don't look familiar, post your code, or the endpoint you're requesting and I'd be more than happy to try to get you sorted out.

Comment: I am indeed using `watchPosition`, that's the position object I'm referring to - `position.coords.speed`. I take it that means it's in m/s?

Comment: Yep, it's in meters/second. Here's the documentation on the speed attribute: https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#speed.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find any documentation on google maps api position object in relation to speed, but you can calculate the speed yourself given two sets of gps coords.

Here is a link on how to do this in Java but the idea's will be the same.
http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/11/14/algorithm-to-calculate-speed-from-two-gps-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-time-difference/

That way you are doing the calculations yourself and not relying on someone else to do it for you.